# fade effect with slideperview in swiper plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swipe

I am working on slider with swiper plugin.my problem is fade effect not working with slideperview.
my jquery code is:

```
   var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        loop: true,
        fadeEffect: { crossFade: true },
        slidesPerView: 3,
        initialSlide:1,
        centeredSlides: true,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
    });
```

my codepen is 
https://codepen.io/zariJoon/pen/WaqawG

Comment: "Be sure to have the `effect` param set to `fade` in order for this to work." -- [Fade Effect](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#fade-effect).